# Making ONLY part of an axis show in an R plot

Tags: r, plot

**Background:** As you can see in the image below, currently the y-axis extends from -2 to 2 (i.e, the y-axis contains both positive and negative values).

**Question:**

*Keeping everything as shown in the image below*, I was wondering is there might be a way to **only show the positive part of the y-axis (from 0 on) and somehow HIDE the negative portion of the y-axis? (*please see the R code further below*)**

[image]

**Here is the R code:**

```
if(!require(library(plotrix))){install.packages('plotrix') }
library(plotrix)          ## A package for drawing ellipses ##


plot(1, ty='n', ann = F, axes = F, xlim = c(-4, 6), ylim = c(-2.5, 2) ) ## platform for ellipses

axis(side = 2)   ## HERE is my question ## ???


draw.ellipse(x = rep(1, 11), y = rep(-1.2, 11), 
     a = seq(1, 6, by = .4), b = seq(1/4.5, 6/4.5 , by = .4/4.5 ), 
     lty = 2, border = 'gray60' )       ## Draw multiple Concentric ellipses ##


AA <- seq(-4, 6, len = 13)     ## A range of values on the x-xis just like "xlim" ##
BB <- dcauchy( AA, 1, .95)*5   ## The Height for the AA according to a distribution ##

segments(AA, rep(-1.2, length(AA) ), AA, BB, lty = 3, lwd = 2, col= 'green4' )

curve(dcauchy(x, 1, .95)*5, -4, 6, add = T, col ='magenta', lwd = 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `?axis`. You just need to specify the `at` argument.

`axis(side = 2, at = 0:2)`